# Help and/or info comand simple

Tags: shell-script, icons, info

How can i write information for a shell file that i have in my `bin` to write the information that the help command or the info command use.

p.s. can you answer the question with simple steps or code snipe’s not just links to pages that i then have to attempt to under stand

it is just that i want to write a reminder to the end user after a have given them the software. more than one line.and the program to write it in to be gui

Comment: sorry i don't read your first line . what do you mean ?

Comment: i mean the content that goes in the `info` and `help` comand but i do not mind witch

Comment: there is a "info" command but people don't use that unless they are big fans of rms . you write those documentations in separate files following some specific style .

Comment: and the "help" command is generally provided by the interpreter . we do not customise that ofter .

Comment: do you know of the style for the info file or how to use it @soubunmei

Comment: [this is an example file in _info_ format](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/html_node/Short-Sample-Texinfo-File.html#Short-Sample-Texinfo-File) , if you really want code snippet instead of theory . still , don't use info .

Comment: by **don't use info** i mean you may want to write in other formats than the _info_ format .

Comment: where would i put the file

Comment: if you feel like to see how to write a manual to be read by the _man(1)_ programme i can post an answer . **anyway edit the question , say clealy what you have done , say what you are doing , say what you want , say what you do not want .**

Comment: Is the man program gui

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20919/discussion-between-soubunmei-and-jhondoe).